# javascript document.body.scrollTop returns 2 values

Tags: javascript, scroll, height

im trying use javascript document.body.scrollTop to get current scroll px and compare with window height in a one page website(5 sections).
My main goal is user scroll in an area of 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 5/5 of total height, page will automatically stay in that section.
But in my code, i got document.body.scrollTop showing me 2 different values, rly confuse me.

```
window.onscroll = function() {

var winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight
var scrollH = document.body.scrollTop

console.log(winH, scrollD);


if ( winH < (scrollD*1.2) ) {
  console.log(winH , scrollH)

}}
```

In console when scrolling will display 2 different set of height with same vars.
example:

- 518 218 (from 1st console log, which is correct my window is 518px high, and scrolled 218px)
- 218 218 (i dont get why this one has same value, becuz it always shows same value so the if statement is broken.)

ps:if i change document.body.scrollTop as global var, console will show cant read propriety of scrollTop value of Null.  Why its fine in function?

Thanks

Comment: @Prasath-k hi, tks for the help, innerheight will solve the problem, but i still confused by 2 different outcome from the console log. and why global var of scrollTop is null